# Send Bluetooth Data to Android App (HC 05)

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05, android

I'm struggling to send data **strictly from** my arduino UNO **to** an android app using bluetooth module HC 05. I am able to send/receive using 1) the serial monitor in arduino IDE and 2) Bluetooth Chat android app (a sample project in Android Studio). But when I use software serial using pins 3,2 instead of TX/RX on my UNO, the Bluetooth Chat app cannot connect to my HC 05. I think I'm missing something important.

My end goal is **not** to send messages like a chat. It will be a very simple flag-based system where, for example, an event occurs on my arduino which causes it to transmit character 'h' through bluetooth, which is then received by my android app. In android receive: if 'h' is read by bluetooth, doSomething(). I don't need to send anything from my android app to the arduino right now, but that would be nice to know.

I just thought I could test my bluetooth functionality with this Bluetooth Chat sample app. Now, that seems like a poor place to start.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `strictly`? it has no meaning in the sentence that you used. ... you could have used the word `joyfully` and it would be just as meaningless. ... i am not trying to be snarky, i am just questioning the meaning of the word

Comment: one thing you need to do when developing hardware and developing code, you need to clearly identify the problem. ... your problem is `cannot connect to my HC 05 when I use software serial using pins 3,2` ... your question should be about that, everything else that you mentioned is just a distraction from the real problem

Comment: @jsotola The serial monitor on my PC receives android messages fine. As far as I know about this, and I don't know much since I just began this android/arduino communication endeavor, the issue seems to be *strictly* transmission from arduino to android. Obviously the issue could be android reception. Sorry I'm spotty on the description of my issue. I'm experienced with serial communication but new to bluetooth. I suppose I could use some advice on where to start.

Comment: Another thing. People seem to be using a software serial abstraction to accomplish what I'm trying to do. But I don't understand why one would use a software serial and not tx/rx 0 and 1.